# Some specific things regarding the Winter Bash

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2015

I enjoy the Winter Bash and want to encourage our community to participate. But please participate sanely.

1. Please stop flagging a bajillion comments. I like comment clean-up as much as the next mod, but the hat is specifically for your *own* comments. You can delete those yourself, please and thank you.
2. There is a secret hat for posting a bug on Meta (plus some other conditions). Do not post a fake bug on Meta to get this hat. If you want this hat (and I really do), find a real bug to report.

Thank you.

Comment: What? There's a hat for flagging? That seems like promoting tattlers. Uncool man.

Comment: @Mitch No, but there's a hat for deleting a load of your *own* comments, and that often makes people flag others' comments as obsolete. (There are *badges* for helpful flags though.)

Comment: @randal oh. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

but wait a minute. Someone posted a [Meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/shall-we-just-toss-the-winter-hats-into-the-bin) in an attempt to earn a hat!

Well, self, that's true, but that Meta post contains all that is needed for everyone else in the community to earn the same hat. The hat for posting a bug only goes to the one who posted the question. Plus, it dilutes the [legitimate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294808/what-meaning-is-legitimately-gaining) use of the bug tag. So please don't do it for kicks, even if you think Grace Hopper is the bee's knees.

Comment: It took me a while but I get it now. Hopper -> bugs -> bees. Where the knees comes from, [that's another ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47088/where-does-the-phrase-the-bees-knees-originate-from).